# How to add Real time collaboration in CKEditor5 in React Application?

Tags: ckeditor

I have edited `index.d.js` file which contains all the plugin details and which refers to `<CKEditor   editor={ ClassicEditor }/>`

Comment: Please share if you get any solution to this or if you implement it on your own